# Error when I change the name of an interaction command discord.js v13

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a clear command, but I started with the name for it being ping. Now I wrote the entire code necessary for the command, I want to change the name to clear, but then it gives the error: `TypeError: command.execute is not a function`. When I change it back to ping, it works fine without any errors. I also ran the deploy file. Do I need to write the code again or is there an easier way to fix it?

code when the name is ping:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!')
        .addNumberOption(option => option.setName('number').setDescription('Amount of messages you want to delete!').setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const amount = interaction.options.getNumber('number');
        
        const amountParsed = parseInt(amount);

        if(amountParsed > 99) return interaction.reply('You cannot delete more than 99 messages at a time!');

        interaction.channel.bulkDelete(amountParsed + 1, true);

        await interaction.reply(`Cleared ${amountParsed} messages!`);

        setInterval(() => interaction.channel.bulkDelete(1, true), 5000)
    },
};
```

Code when the name is clear:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('clear')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!')
        .addNumberOption(option => option.setName('number').setDescription('Amount of messages you want to delete!').setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const amount = interaction.options.getNumber('number');
        
        const amountParsed = parseInt(amount);

        if(amountParsed > 99) return interaction.reply('You cannot delete more than 99 messages at a time!');

        interaction.channel.bulkDelete(amountParsed + 1, true);

        await interaction.reply(`Cleared ${amountParsed} messages!`);

        setInterval(() => interaction.channel.bulkDelete(1, true), 5000)
    },
};
```

deploy-commands.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./src/Data/config.json');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/iCommands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./src/iCommands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}
    
const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Succesfully registerd application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

index.js:

```
console.clear()

const fs = require('fs')

const { Collection } = require('discord.js');

const Client = require("./Structures/Client.js");

const config = require("./Data/config.json");

const client = new Client();

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/iCommands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`../src/iCommands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});





client.start(config.token);
```

Comment: And can we have your command handler?

Comment: I added it to the question @Leau

Comment: I think I found out why it happends. I have a not interaction command thats called clear, so I think thats why it doesnt work